# VBScript to parse a line until the marker character is met

Tags: string, parsing, vbscript

How to parse a line until the marker string/character is met.

Eg.

```
    <a href="/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&number=100001">
..
    <a href="/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&number=200001">
..
    <a href="/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&number=300001">
```

These strings can occur any part of the html file.My question goes like this.

My start marker is "/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&number=" and
end marker is " " ", I should save those six digit variable into some text file.

Any solution will be very much appreciated.

Thanks You.

Comment: If you want to extract the number just replace each "<a href="/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&number=" with a empty string and replace "">" also with an empty string.

Comment: Nopes this data comes at run time and gets refreshed after a while. So when ever I get this log. I would save it onto a file. Then I would like to parse the entire line in the log file.

In this case parse until I find "<a href="/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&number=" then get the 6 digit number until I find ".

This is pretty tricky but Right() isnt helping me the way I wanted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be easy with RegExp:

```
dim f
dim r
dim item
dim rMatches

' .. .-> read the content of the file into f

set r =  new regexp

r.pattern = "\/stamp\/stamp.jsp\?tp=&number=(\d+)\"""
r.global = true
set rMatches = r.execute(f)

for each item in rMatches
    msgbox item.submatches(0)
next
```

Comment: Hi, great, then please 'accept' the answer to spread points and so others can see that this question has been solved.